# Помогите справиться с комбинаторным бумом

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Проблема в следующем есть таблица (прайс) где товары приходят со следующими значениями

1. продавать поштучно (единица товара), упаковками, тысячами.
2. вес товара шт/кг, 1000 шт/кг, упаковка/кг
3. цена так же приходит по разному за шт, 1000 шт, за упаковку

записать в базу нужно в следующем виде

1. единица измерения (ед.и) - в чем (шт/тыс/уп)
2. вес ед.и
3. цена за ед.и

Как вы понимаете если лепить на каждый вариант отдельный метод просчета получаем  "комбинаторный бум". Тем более если добавятся варианты.
Рисовать таблицы зависимостей/считать всё ко всему, а потом подставлять нужные   чревато потерями производительности.

Иными словами нужен совет куда копать, как с этим поступить или какой шаблон поможет это решить.

Судя по всему невнятно объяснил проблему:
Штука в том что единица товара может прийти в одном виде (единице измерения) шт, цена 5 тыс.шт - 700р, вес товара в другом соотношении 2,7 кг на упаковку, вес либо на 1000 либо на штуку либо на упаковку.

Comment: непонятно, зачем нужны варианты, вы же всё написали. Единицы измерения храните текстом/enum'ом, и не придавайте им никакого значения. Есть цена на единицу товара(кг, 100шт, упаковка, не важно), есть вес. Или есть возможность распечатывать упаковку для продажи? Скажем 10 карандашей стоят 15р., заказать можно 7шт.?

Comment: если есть возможность один и тот же товар продавать в разных формах - нужно заводить их как разные товары. упаковки отдельно, штуки отдельно. Есть такой термин, как артикул, учётная единица товара.

Comment: Если хотите шаблон то вам вполне подойдет фабрика